# Should havdalah be done in the sukkah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sukkah, sukkot, havdalah

On sukkot, does havdalah have do be done in the sukkah after Shabbat? Does Halacha require this, or can it be done anywhere? If it is not required, is there still preference for it?

As always, sources from the community are appreciated.

Comment: In the blue tehilas Hashem siddur on page 297 it gives the instructionnto make leshev basukah

Comment: @Dude Chabad avoids drinking at all outside the sukkah, so it would be in the sukkah by default. For others, it might depend on the drink. As for the bracha, see here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20601/6592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rav Doniel Neustadt provides a good rundown [here](https://outorah.org/p/117598/):

> Question: Must one make havdalah in the sukkah?
>
> Discussion: **Mishnah Berurah rules that since one generally makes havdalah at home, he should make it in the sukkah**.<sup>1</sup> However, it is unclear whether or not one should recite the berachah of leisheiv over havdalah.<sup>2</sup> It is therefore advisable to eat more than a kebeitzah of some mezonos-item after havdalah and to then stay in the sukkah for some time (as above). A person following this suggestion would recite the berachah of leishev basukkah not before drinking the havdalah wine but, rather, before the berachah of mezonos.<sup>3</sup> Additionally, if one has the mezonos on the table while making havdalah, the mezonos should be covered.<sup>4</sup>

---

> <sup>1</sup> [**639:30**](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.639.30?lang=bi). That is, irrespective of the issue of whether drinking wine requires a sukkah, havdalah, as an activity that is ordinarily done at home, should be done in the sukkah. Based on this reasoning, it would ostensibly apply even according to the opinions that wine does not require a sukkah; it would apply to one who is not drinking a full revi’is and to a person who is not actually drinking the wine, but merely hearing it from someone else. However, Sha’ar Hatziyun there states that one who ordinarily hears havdalah in shul may do so on Sukkos as well.
>
> <sup>2</sup> See Lu’ach Eretz Yisro’el.
>
> <sup>3</sup> Since the wine may not warrant the berachah, the berachah should rather be recited over the mezonos; see Luach Eretz Yisrael; Sefer Hasukkah, new edition, I, chapter 33, footnote 18. R’ Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, however, would recite the berachah before borei pri hagafen even when relying on the mezonos he ate afterwards (see Halichos Shlomo, 9, footnote 85; Sefer Hasukkah (new edition) II, p. 600.
>
> <sup>4</sup> [Shulchan Aruch 299:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.299.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: The bracha is for a different question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20601/759

Comment: The answer here is "should" which is quite trivial since everything should be in the sukka (except bathroom). The interesting question is how much do you have to.